# Flash video disappearing from page prematurely on first load

Tags: flash, actionscript, video-streaming

We're putting together one of those "greeting spokesperson" videos for our website.  The video is about 30 seconds long, and on the first load, it always disappears in the middle of a sentence.  Refresh the page, and it works fine thereafter.

The video plays through a FLV Player inside a SWF.  The SWF is 695 frames long and has the following characteristics:

- A 'fade-out' alpha tween starting at Frame 685
- A Stop action at the very last frame
- The following code on the FLV player:

  ```
  on (complete) {
      getURL('javascript:removeIt();');    }
  ```

This is supposed to trigger when the video is done.  The "removeIt()" function contains a jQuery statement that fades out the div containing the video.  Clicking the "X" also triggers the removeIt() function.

The link is http://test.thestevenscompany.com

My question is why is this fading out too soon, only on the first page load?  I have tried the following:

- Reducing the quality to 200 kilobit (hence the choppy quality)
- Having the player buffer 12 seconds before playing
- Removing the ActionScript call to removeIt() from the last frame to the complete event on the FLV player.

Any help is appreciated, this is coming due soon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your timeline animation completes faster then the streamed/progressed video.

You should add a CuePoint to your FLV so it can tell your Flash application when it's ended and ready to fade out. When the video reaches the CuePoint and triggers the `CuePointEvent` you can start fading out your stuff.

**More info about CuePoints:**
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CuePointEvent.html#CuePointEvent()

Good luck,
Rob